# Unity: downloading images and keeping them after scene load (WebGL)

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, download, unity-webgl

guys. I'm making a "virtual expo" in WebGl where users can navigate through stands and see images of all the products. To make it a lot faster to load, my build does not include the images, they are downloaded from a server after the game starts. It also enables me to change them on the server and automatically update the next time the user refreshes its browser. It works alright.

The problem is the game has 7 areas that separate the different stand categories, and every time you come back to a previous one, all images have to download again, making it tedious for the user and bandwith heavy for the server. I dont want to store them all in memory with "dont destroy on load" or similar methods because they're quite a bunch and the memory requirements for the users would rise significantly.

How could I store them at runtime in a folder (in the user's end) once they are downloaded? so the next time the user loads a previous area they dont have to download them again but instead load them from the folder in case they exist already.

Something like "resources load" but for webgl. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: They will be cached by the browser, if your server delivers them with http response header “Cache-Control” set to “public, max-age=3600”. So they will be cached for an hour. And in the Unity Web Request set manually the “Cache-Control” to “public”.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, @JeanLuc! Let me try it and I´ll get back to you, but I think you got it

Comment: This is an area I don´t know enough about, so it´s taking me some time to understand how it works, but it seems to be the right path. How can I refer to this cache? I mean, how could I check, for instance, if an image is already downloaded to the cache, if so, assign it, if not, download it?
Thanks again

Comment: It’s called HTTP Caching: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Comment: There is a Cache-Control directive called “only-if-cached”, which might work, if you load from the same server.

Comment: Thanks Jean. You´ve really been a great help. I hope after all this pointers I can get it working.